# save java collection in a database

Tags: java, mysql, collections

I have made a java collection (named collection) and I'm having trouble saving it into a database.
I think the the easiest way to do that, would be to insert the collections objects one by one (with the for each loop) in the Persons table by sending a query like this:

`for (Person p: collection){
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Persons (Name,Surname,ID,Phone) values (a.getName(),a.getSurname(),a.getID(),a.getPhone();");
        }`

BUT i receive this error on compilation: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

a.getName(),a.getSurname(),a.getID(),a.getPhone() are getters, is there a way to use them inside a sql query?

Comment: here what is `a` in code ? any object ?

Comment: Currently you are just trying to insert the names a.getName(), a.getSurname() into the database. It does not resolve these into their values. Perhaps use String.format from the String API.

Comment: You should better use prepared statement for this kind of task

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a prepared statement:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
String insert = "INSERT INTO Persons (Name,Surname,ID,Phone) values (?,?,?,?);";
PreparedStatement pStmnt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
pstmnt.setString(1,a.getName());
pstmnt.setString(2,a.getSurname());
pStmnt.setInt(3,a.getId());
pStmnt.setString(3,a.getPhone());

pStmnt.execteUpdate();
```

Prepared statements protect against [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) and should be used as much as possible.

You can wrap this inside of a loop without any diffifculties - just make sure your objects are referring to the right thing:

```
for(Person p : collection{
    pstmnt.setString(1,p.getName());
    pstmnt.setString(2,p.getSurname());
    pStmnt.setInt(3,p.getId());
    pStmnt.setString(3,p.getPhone());

    pStmnt.execteUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Great ! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

You have a semi-colon inside the `values` statement and you need the closing parentheses.  Try this:

```
for (Person p: collection){ statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Persons (Name,Surname,ID,Phone)
                                     values (a.getName(),a.getSurname(),a.getID(),a.getPhone())"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use :

```
(Person p: collection){ statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Persons (Name,Surname,ID,Phone) values (" + a.getName()+","+ a.getSurname()+","a.getID().toString()+","+a.getPhone().toString()+";)"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

**can you please try this:**

```
for (Person p: collection){ statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Persons (Name,Surname,ID,Phone) values("+a.getName()+","+a.getSurname()+","+a.getID()+","+a.getPhone()+";"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add them this way :

```
for (Person p: collection){ 
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Persons (Name,Surname,ID,Phone) values("+a.getName()+","+a.getSurname()+","+a.getID()+","+a.getPhone()+")");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try looking at prepared statements. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Person p: collection)
{ 
      statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Persons (Name,Surname,ID,Phone) values("+a.getName()+","+a.getSurname()+","+a.getID()+","+a.getPhone()+")");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove ";" from the statement after a.getPhone()